# How can I get the numer of failed tests from Invoke-Pester?

Tags: powershell, pester

I have a few Pester tests running fine in the console, but I would like to run the tests automatically and send a message if any test fails. I read the option -EnableExit causes Invoke-Pester to return the numer of failed tests. But whenever I use -EnableExit the powershell console closes, regardless if a test failed. It is Pester version 4.7.3. PSVersion 5.1.

Is `Invoke-Pester -EnableExit` supposed to close the shell?
How do I get the number of failed tests?

runs fine:
`Invoke-Pester -Script D:\tmp\PowerShell\dummy1.Tests.ps1`

closes the shell window:
`Invoke-Pester -Script D:\tmp\PowerShell\dummy1.Tests.ps1 -EnableExit`

I expect to get an integer as output, but the console window closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get just the number of failed tests by doing this:

```
(Invoke-Pester -Path D:\tmp\PowerShell\dummy1.Tests.ps1 -PassThru -Show None).FailedCount
```

If you want other data (passed/skipped count, test results, etc), then pass the output to a variable, then process further:

`$testResults = Invoke-Pester -Path D:\tmp\PowerShell\dummy1.Tests.ps1 -PassThru -Show None`

Comment: I like this answer, it is concise.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the number of failed tests by using the `-PassThru` switch on `Invoke-Pester`. For example:

```
$TestResults = Invoke-Pester -PassThru
```

My `$TestResults` variable then has a `FailedCount` property with the number of tests that failed. You can then use this as part of a pipeline to have the pipeline fail if there are failed tests:

```
If ($TestResults.FailedCount -gt 0) { Throw "There were $($TestResults.FailedCount) failed tests" }
```

Here's an example of the other things `-PassThru` returns:

```
TagFilter         :
ExcludeTagFilter  :
TestNameFilter    :
ScriptBlockFilter :
TotalCount        : 230
PassedCount       : 229
FailedCount       : 1
SkippedCount      : 0
PendingCount      : 0
InconclusiveCount : 0
Time              : 00:00:43.8675480
TestResult        : {@{ErrorRecord=; ParameterizedSuiteName=; Describe=Testing all Modules against default
                    PSScriptAnalyzer rule-set; Parameters=System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary;
                    Passed=True; Show=All; FailureMessage=; Time=00:00:00.7463377; Name=passes the PSScriptAnalyzer
                    Rule PSAlignAssignmentStatement; Result=Passed; Context=Testing Module
                    'C:\Users\wragg\github\PowerShell-Subnet\Subnet\Subnet.psm1'; StackTrace=}, @{ErrorRecord=;
                    ParameterizedSuiteName=; Describe=Testing all Modules against default PSScriptAnalyzer rule-set;
                    Parameters=System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary; Passed=True; Show=All;
                    FailureMessage=; Time=00:00:02.2605400; Name=passes the PSScriptAnalyzer Rule
                    PSAvoidUsingCmdletAliases; Result=Passed; Context=Testing Module
                    'C:\Users\wragg\github\PowerShell-Subnet\Subnet\Subnet.psm1'; StackTrace=}, @{ErrorRecord=;
                    ParameterizedSuiteName=; Describe=Testing all Modules against default PSScriptAnalyzer rule-set;
                    Parameters=System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary; Passed=True; Show=All;
                    FailureMessage=; Time=00:00:00.0865224; Name=passes the PSScriptAnalyzer Rule
                    PSAvoidAssignmentToAutomaticVariable; Result=Passed; Context=Testing Module
                    'C:\Users\wragg\github\PowerShell-Subnet\Subnet\Subnet.psm1'; StackTrace=}, @{ErrorRecord=;
                    ParameterizedSuiteName=; Describe=Testing all Modules against default PSScriptAnalyzer rule-set;
                    Parameters=System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary; Passed=True; Show=All;
                    FailureMessage=; Time=00:00:00.0590095; Name=passes the PSScriptAnalyzer Rule
                    PSAvoidDefaultValueSwitchParameter; Result=Passed; Context=Testing Module
                    'C:\Users\wragg\github\PowerShell-Subnet\Subnet\Subnet.psm1'; StackTrace=}...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-PassThru` switch parameter of `Invoke-Pester`

```
$Result = Invoke-Pester -Script C:\temp\test.tests.ps1 -PassThru
$Result
$Result.FailedCount
```